# Why MySql DATETIME takes 8 Bytes instead of 6 Bytes?

Tags: mysql, database

MySql DATE is occupying 3 Bytes and TIME is occupying 3 Bytes but DATETIME is taking 8 Bytes. I assume like it should be 6 Bytes (3+3) instead of 8 Bytes. What is the logic behind this and why the extra two bytes are used?

Comment: Probably the space between the date and the time?

Comment: See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/date-and-time-data-type-representation.html for details on mysql data type representation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to MySQL internals [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/date-and-time-data-type-representation.html), it's needed because of specific storage requirements:

```
+-----------+------------------------+---------------------+
|   YEAR    | 1 byte, little endian  |      Unchanged      |
+-----------+------------------------+---------------------+
|   DATE    | 3 bytes, little endian |      Unchanged      |
+-----------+------------------------+---------------------+
|           |                        | 3 bytes +           |
|   TIME    | 3 bytes, little endian | fractional-seconds  |
|           |                        | storage, big endian |
+-----------+------------------------+---------------------+
|           |                        | 4 bytes +           |
| TIMESTAMP | 4 bytes, little endian | fractional-seconds  |
|           |                        | storage, big endian |
+-----------+------------------------+---------------------+
|           |                        | 5 bytes +           |
| DATETIME  | 8 bytes, little endian | fractional-seconds  |
|           |                        | storage, big endian |
+-----------+------------------------+---------------------+
```

In particular, `DATETIME` has 8 bytes:

- 4 bytes: integer for date represented as `YYYY×10000 + MM×100 + DD`
- 4 bytes: integer for time represented as `HH×10000 + MM×100 + SS`

So it's important to realize, that output representation and storage representation are two very different things. As you can see, structure for datetime is two integers with some internal calculations for both parts - date and time.

Comment: It is confusing when you copy this table without the before-mysql-5.6.4 and after-mysql-5.6.4 headers.